# mismatch with count number of files within a directory in unix

Tags: bash, unix

`ls -1 | wc -l` gives me count of 4209 where as `ls -l | wc -l` gives me count of 4210.

Is "-1" reducing overall count by 1? Which I feel is unlikely.

So what is the correct count of files in my directory?

Comment: There is [Unix&Linux.StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) where you can get better help.

Comment: I got the answer myself. When you do ls -l, it add total bytes at the top as one line, which need not to be counted. So 'ls -1" gives the correct count.

Answer (score 0):

`ls -l` shows an extra line at the beginning marked `total` which is the disk usage of listed files in blocks not including the sub directories. But it should be ignored here as were are to take the count and `wc` makes each line counts. Here `ls -1 | wc -l` gives you the correct count.

The **-1** option is passed just to list one file per line. You can have the same output with `ls | wc -l`

Refer here : http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x700.html